# Not able to import package/class chesspesso

Tags: java, chess

I am trying to make a sort of chess game and for which i am trying to use chesspresso package of java.
I am doing -
import chesspresso.position.Position;

but everytime i am geeting package chesspresso.position doesnot exist. If someone knows how to incorporate chesspresso in my java project . Please help.

Comment: What kind of project are you doing? Did you make a brand new one? Is it a Maven-based project?

Comment: Make sure that the jar file containing the chesspresso package is on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such package in the core Java language distribution, so you have to get it from somewhere else and include it on your classpath at both compile- and runtime.
The JVM documentation will tell you how to do that.